# Adding browse file button to adaptive card of MS bot framework using nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using `Nodejs` sdk for bot development. For uploading files in `MSBot` webchat we have default icon on the bottom left of chat window.

But what I am trying is to allow the user to upload files on a button click like we do in case of html `"input type="file"`. I tried to implement it using adaptive cards but adaptive cards only support an input type of time, text etc, but not file.

Is there a way to have this file upload option on button click in the chat window? Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Please share the code of what you have tried first.

Comment: You'll need to post an activity yourself, client side.  This example enables drag/drop file upoload in webfchat, and should help you get started in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689918/86646

Comment: @AdamRichardson  
I referred to this url http://adaptivecards.io/samples/Inputs.html  and tried something like this {
"type": "Input.File",
"placeholder": "Upload File",
"style": "File",
"maxLength": 0,
"id": "FileVal"
}, 
 
but it  is giving me the below error "Unknown element type: Input.File"

Comment: @EricDahlvang Let us consider the sample bot where in i am submitting an application form. As part of that I want bot to send me the button "upload resume" and when I click on that button I should be able to select files. I referred to the link that you have shared, If we go with that process can we be able to show that button to the user whenever is required?

Comment: You would need to customize the WebChat control to have a File Input button within the chat stream.  That is currently not a feature. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/